# How to customize the column names of the embedded object?

Tags: java, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to use the Spring Data JDBC and I cannot understand if there is a possibility to customize the column names of the embedded object (in JPA we use `@AttributeOverrides` for this).

In my model I created a class `Amount` they I would like to reuse in different types of objects.

```
public class Amount {
    private BigDecimal value;
    private String currency;

   //getters, settes, contructors
}
```

I would like to save it like 2 embedded values in two tables: `houses` and `cars`.

In the table `houses` I want the columns to be called `house_price_value` and `house_price_currency`. In the table `cars` they should be called `car_eval_value` and `car_eval_currency`.

```
public class House {
      @Id
      Long id;
      int numberOfRooms; 
      @Embedded
      Amount amount;

   //other attributes, getters, setters, constructors
}
```

```
public class Car {
      @Id
      Long id;
      String model;
      @Embedded
      Amount amount;

   //other attributes, getters, setters, constructors
}
```

The problem is that the annotation `@Column` is applicable only to the attribute and should be set on the `Amount`-class level. which makes this class not reusable.

In JPA I would have used this but in JDBC this annotation is not found:

```
@AttributeOverrides(value = {
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "house_price_value")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "currency", column = @Column(name = "house_price_currency"))
})
```

Don't I see another solution?

Comment: Wasn't that suitable for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.custom-column-name

Comment: @mate00 not completely. I should put these columns inside the Amount-class and therefore I don't know how to customize it for different tables and make it reusable

Comment: I think I'm not following. Do you want to use Amount in more than one table (let's say A, B and C), but only in table A you want a different name for the column than in B and C?

Comment: @mate00 yes, almost. in all the tables I want to have different column names for "value" and "currency"

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work with `value` attribute of the `@Embedded`. This value should contain a prefix.

```
@Embedded(value = "house_price_")
Amount approvalValue;
```